# Docker: fail linking with mysql DB

Tags: mysql, docker, matomo

Am trying to connect [Mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) container with [Piwik](https://hub.docker.com/r/marvambass/piwik/) 'php app' firs i run the mysql container like this:

```
docker run --name piwik -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql
```

Then am trying to run and link the piwik app with this command:

```
docker run -d -e PIWIK_MYSQL_USER=root -e PIWIK_MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456 -e PIWIK_MYSQL_DBNAME=piwik -e PIWIK_MYSQL_PREFIX=piwik_ --link piwik:piwikmysql  --name vpiwik marvambass/piwik
```

However when I check the logs I see this error:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (0)
>> no DB installed, MYSQL User or Password specified - seems like the first start
> exec docker CMD
nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/12 20:24:42 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/12 20:24:42 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
[notice] 1#1: try again to bind() after 500ms
[notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
[notice] 1#1: nginx/1.11.4
[notice] 1#1: built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
[notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 4.4.14-moby
[notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
[notice] 1#1: start worker processes
[notice] 1#1: start worker process 141
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql server (host) name is different DB name.  To fix your problem, change to,

```
--link piwik:mysql
```